# Can I host multiple sites with one Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-server, vps, website

I currently have VPS server and I pay around $75 per month and I get:

```
40GB HD
2Gb RAM
100GB BW
6 core cpu (but i dont use much)
```

I have only one live website running and traffic is only max 100 user visit per day. I mostly do the my testing stuff and some of my inter sites for playing with coding.

But I do need one server.

I am thinking of moving to Amazon EC2 if the price diff is not so much because then I can learn some more stuff.

I am thinking of getting the `3 years Heavy utilization Reserved instance` because my server will be running all day and night. I tried their online caluclator

with

`Medium Instance Heavy reserved for 3 years` for EC2 it comes `$31 per month(effective price)` and for EBS and S3 , I think even if thats it $40 for all other stuff. I will be at no loss for what I am getting at present. Am i correct or I missed something??

Now In my current VPS I have Apache for PHP sites and MOD wsgi for python sites.

I am not sure if I will be able to do all that stuff in Amazon EC2. Can I host python and PHP sites both in Amazon EC2 instance using Named `Virtual Hosts` and `Ngnix`

Comment: You're massively overpaying for your current specs so EC2 would be okay. However, this question is off topic here.

Comment: Don't get a three year instance. AWS prices will fall in that time. One year commitments are almost always a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 100 visits/day isn't much

100 visits per day isn't much. In fact 100 visits every couple of minutes isn't much! Unless you have a very inefficient setup it seems very unlikely you'll need THAT much computing power.

Of course it's possible you have some scripts or programs that use up lots of RAM (or something strange like that), but assuming fairly average usage on a typical LAMP setup you can probably get away with a SMALL instance and easily handle 100 visits per day.

### start off with On Demand

My advice would be to start off with ON-DEMAND instance, and after you've got everything up and running nicely, and you have a good idea about what resources you need, you can swap them over for RESERVED instances.

### Can I install/run xyz on AWS?

> Can I host python and PHP sites both in Amazon EC2 instance using
>   Named Virtual Hosts and Ngnix

With EC2 you have full control over the OS. You can install packages, compile your own software and configure things like Web Servers to run multiple websites.

You can run PHP and Python (I've personally done each of these and more, node.js etc).

You can configure things to run on different ports easily. You can create VPNs and bind IP Addresses to your server, plus a whole lot more.

There are even services like OpsWorks that can do the setup and maintenance of your EC2s and the software that runs inside the OS.